# BottomNavigationView not showing anything in android studio

Tags: java, android, xml, menu, navigation

I am unable to see the bottom navigation menu bar inside the android studio layout.
I already tried adding dependencies' but nothing happen and there isn't any error in xml code given below.
Here are my xml files:
**bottom_navigation.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item
    android:title="Home"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_baseline_home_24"
    android:id="@+id/nav_home"/>
    <item
        android:title="Favourite"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_baseline_favorite_24"
        android:id="@+id/nav_fav"/>

    <item
        android:title="Search"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_baseline_search_24"
        android:id="@+id/nav_search"/>
</menu>
```

**bottom_navigation.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
   <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="100dp"
       app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
       app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
       app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
      app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

[Image Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DXSMu.png)

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a preview issue with `implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.5.0'`.

It's working fine on `implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'`

You should check if the bottom navigation is fine in the app output.

Comment: Bottom Navigation is fine output. But It still not visible in design view after implementation

Comment: Thanks for answering though 

Answer (score 0):

Issues with height wrap content. If u set height it will works. Issues from 1.5.0 onwards